# Как изменить размер reCAPTCHA

Tags: css, recaptcha

Как изменить размер reCAPTCHA?

Answer (score 6):

Ответ из комментария [lexxl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/196573/lexxl):

Попробуйте

- либо использовать вариант "компакт" из [документации](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param)
- либо использовать inline-стили: `<style="transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0">`

Answer (score 0):

Можно не инлайново

```
    .g-recaptcha, .g-recaptcha div{ 
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    } 
   .g-recaptcha iframe, body > div[style]:last-of-type
   { transform: scale(0.75);
   transform-origin: left top;
   }
```

Или с помощью javaScript и библиотеки jQuery

```
$(function() { 
var reCaptchaWidth = 302;
var containerWidth = $('.respon-kaptcha').width(); 
if(reCaptchaWidth > containerWidth) {
var reCaptchaScale = containerWidth / reCaptchaWidth;
$('.g-recaptcha').css({
'transform':'scale('+reCaptchaScale+')',
'transform-origin':'left top'
});
} 
});
```

Капчу в div с классом .respon-kaptcha

Answer (score 0):

```
var captchasAr = document.querySelectorAll(".g-recaptcha");
    captchasAr.forEach(function (captcha) {
        var reCaptchaWidth = 304;
        var containerWidth = captcha.parentNode.offsetWidth;
        if (reCaptchaWidth > containerWidth) {
            captcha.parentNode.style.transform = 'scale(' + (containerWidth / reCaptchaWidth) + ')';
            captcha.parentNode.style.transformOrigin = 'left top';
            captcha.parentNode.style.width = (reCaptchaWidth / containerWidth) * 100 + '%';
        }
    });
```