# Длина блока капчи Google

Tags: recaptcha

Как исправить данную неприятность, чтобы за пределы не уходила?
[image]

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть материалы тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541725/Как-изменить-размер-recaptcha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069649/how-to-resize-recaptcha#1069649 http://wikidrupal.ru/Изменить_размер_ReCaptcha